# User profile creation in Rails, with Devise for users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've been learning Rails for a while now and have finally gotten this Pinterest-style application up and running.

What's left for me to do now is create user profiles. I want it to be so that when you visit a user profile, we can see all of the things that particular user uploaded. The problem, however, is that I don't know where to begin. Is there a gem for this sort of task? How do I route each unique username to a different path (eg. abc.com/username)?

By the way -- I have used Devise for authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps I did to create that kind of environment:
Run these commands on the command line:

```
rails new pinterest
rails generate scaffold user name:string age:integer
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Make the route:

```
# routes.rb
get '/:name' => "users#show"
```

Update the set_user method to find the user by name

```
# users_controller.rb
def set_user
  @user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
end
```

Then all you need to do is create a new user and access it using it's name.

Comment: I don't think I will be able to do it this way because of Devise. I do not even see a Users controller here.

Comment: Devise will not be an issue. You can configure it to your needs. If you don't have a users controller it's because you didn't generate one. On which model did you add Devise to?

Comment: I ran `rails generate devise User`.

Comment: If you have a User model, run the "rails generate controller user" command to generate a controller for the users and it's corresponding views.